# Error: read ECONNRESET - HTML-PDF PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, phantomjs, ubuntu-16.04

I am unable to figure out why this issue is occurring and the pdf file is also not being written to disk.

`0|www      | ------------ INSIDE FN -------------
0|www      | -------- before pdf part ---------
0|www      | ------- INSIDE pdf creation -------
0|www      | filename:/var/www/html/public/pdfresults/readinesstest/1492667808.pdf
0|www      | GET /readinesspdf/createreadinesspdf/abcaxxxingh1x1@xyzmail.com/58ef022fa7c9152c47cb8dac 200 79.744 ms - 4581
0|www      | Error: read ECONNRESET
0|www      |     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
0|www      |     at Pipe.onread (net.js:572:26)
PM2        | App [www] with id [0] and pid [13570], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:www id:0
PM2        | App name:www id:0 online`

On another ec2 instance which is a ubuntu 16.04.1, whenever i try to generate the pdf. it throws following error : 
"Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag"

My locale are as follows:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I have tried a lot of solutions mentioned over here but i couldn't fix this by myself.

Comment: And where is the PhantomJS script that you're using?

Comment: I fixed this issue and everything works perfectly on this ec2 instace however i still have the UTF-8 issue on my other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by copying my global modules to my project folder.
Apparently the node project was built on windows and i am deploying it to an ubuntu server. After installing the modules from package.json, they get installed to the global directory, I assume there is a mismatch due to OS conflict in the modules which was resolve by running this.

sudo cp -r /home/ubuntu/node_modules /var/www/html/

Comment: I also fixed the Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag.
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales (Select All and then select en_us for local)
sudo reboot